Dynamic Measure Values Based on Slicer Selection
In a PBI dashboard I'm trying to change the measure based on the selected value of a seperate table.
I followed the steps in https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Dynamic-Measure-Values-Based-on-Slicer-Selection-with-Options/m-p/230151

Measure_1 =
IF(
CONTAINSSTRING(BasEenheden_meta[_Selected_eenheid], "Ger1")=TRUE()
Kwaliteitsbord[hw_intern]
Kwaliteitsbord[gescreend_24u]
)


Measure_1_name =
IF(
CONTAINSSTRING(BasEenheden_meta[_Selected_eenheid], "Ger1")=TRUE()
NAMEOF(Kwaliteitsbord[hw_intern])
NAMEOF(Kwaliteitsbord[gescreend_24u]))

the measure/column have different symbols > maybe that's a reason?
Although it's the same syntax, the value for "Measure_1_name changes", but the value for "Measure_1" doesn't.
Remark: the value for "Measure_1_name" **only **changes when in a card, not when in a column of a table visual.
Is there something I'm overlooking?
Thanks in advance!
